# HDMI no audio on headphones

Tags: sound, hdmi, headphones

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 and my laptop is connected to a TV via **HDMI**. The  sound comes out of the tv just fine, but if I want to plug my **headphones** into the **PC**, nothing happens. The sound keeps coming out of the tv.

Indeed, in the sound settings, output tab, I only see connector: HDMI. Nothing else.

I would like to be able to switch between HDMI audio and headphones. Is it possible?

Comment: What happens when you unplug the HDMI cable? Also, try to reboot, if nothing happens.

Comment: My goal was to avoid rebooting each time. :)
When I unplug the HDMI cable, I'm stuck with the HDMI settings, so no sound.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a very elegant solution, but I found if I run pavucontrol and go to the config tab, I see two entries with pulldown menus set to 'digital stereo (hdmi) output' and 'analog stereo output' respectively. If I set the top menu to 'off' the sound starts coming through my headphones. If I set it back to the original setting and set the second one to 'off', sound starts coming through the external monitor. Something like that might work for you.

Comment: It did. I installed a 3070 FE GPU and all of a sudden my application audio came through only my monitor, even though my sound settings had Schiit Modi 3 selected. Firefox had no problem with coming though my headhpones; only applications like cmus and desktop sound effects didn't seem to get the memo. Odd thing is the 3080 didn't have this problem.